# Unresolved attribute reference "predict()" using scikit-learn in Pycharm

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycharm, warnings

When using a decision tree classifier from scikit-learn, the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html) show you reassigning the variable storing the classifier to the output of itself calling the `fit()` method:

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)
```

However, now if I call the predict method:

```
clf.predict([[1,1]])
```

Pycharm warms me:

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'predict' for class 'object'
```

You can look up the declaration for `fit()` in Pycharm easily, and the method merely returns `self`, so the reassignment is not necessary and you can remove it so that I have instead:

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X, Y)
```

Everything runs smoothly both ways, but Pycharm doesn't give me a warning with the latter. I'm curious, because I'm fairly new to Python and Pycharm, why does it give me this warning? Is there a way to make this IDE recognize that the method returns `self` and therefore is still the same type with the same method `predict()`? Otherwise, is there any way to remove this warning?

Comment: If you click on the light bulb when you hover over it, there is an ignore to ignore the warning and it will go away.

Comment: @gommb No light bulb appears, just the error message.

Comment: If the light bulb doesn't appear by hovering then you need to click the code that is causing the warning a couple times and the light bulb should show up

Comment: Got it, thank you, I was able to ignore it. Still wondering why it gives the warning in the first place though.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do something like this instead to avoid the warning

```
km = KMeans(n_clusters=size)
km.fit(x)
predictions = km.predict(x)
```

For some reason, `fit` returns a object type. I am unsure if it's intentional. KMeans initializer returns the correct type and `fit` is in-place.