# Unresolved attribute reference "predict()", "coef_" and "score" using scikit-learn in Pycharm

Tags: scikit-learn

I cannot resolve  `predict()`, `coef_` and `score` because these is unresolved attribute reference. And, I try to remove this warning but these `model = model.fit(X_train, y_train)` part will be a problem.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
import talib as ta
import yfinance as yf
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

yf.pdr_override()
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo('^NSEI', '2010-01-01')
df = df.dropna()
df = df.iloc[:, :4]
df.head()

df['S_10'] = df['Close'].rolling(window=10).mean()
df['Corr'] = df['Close'].rolling(window=10).corr(df['S_10'])
df['RSI'] = ta.RSI(np.array(df['Close']), timeperiod=20)
df['MACD'] = ta.MOM(np.array(df['Close']), timeperiod=26)
df['Open-Close'] = df['Open'] - df['Close'].shift(1)
df['Open-Open'] = df['Open'] - df['Open'].shift(1)
df = df.dropna()
X = df.iloc[:, :9]

y = np.where(df['Close'].shift(-1) > df['Close'], 1, -1)

split = int(0.7 * len(df))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:split], X[split:], y[:split], y[split:]

model = LinearRegression()
model = model.fit(X_train, y_train)

pd.DataFrame(zip(X.columns, np.transpose(model.coef_)))


predicted = model.predict(X_test)
print(predicted)

print(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, predicted))

print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, predicted))

print(model.score(X_test, y_test))

cross_val = cross_val_score(LinearRegression(), X, y, scoring='accuracy', cv=10)
print(cross_val)
print(cross_val.mean())

df['Predicted_Signal'] = model.predict(X)
df['Nifty_returns'] = np.log(df['Close'] / df['Close'].shift(1))
Cumulative_Nifty_returns = np.cumsum(df[split:]['Nifty_returns'])

df['Startegy_returns'] = df['Nifty_returns'] * df['Predicted_Signal'].shift(1)
Cumulative_Strategy_returns = np.cumsum(df[split:]['Startegy_returns'])

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.plot(Cumulative_Nifty_returns, color='r', label='Nifty Returns')
plt.plot(Cumulative_Strategy_returns, color='g', label='Strategy Returns')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/46994638/10495893?

Comment: After I ignore it and execute the code, I get these ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous targets in print(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, predicted)). And, the problem from predicted = model.predict(X_test). How to solve it?